# Solving trigonometrics functions/equations

Tags: trigonometry

My niece ask me to help her with a school assignment, but I can't identify what type of equation are we solving.

For example:
$\DeclareMathOperator{\tg}{tg}$
$$\sin\alpha=\frac{8\sqrt{11}}{9}$$

or:

$$\tan\alpha=\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{12}$$

The notes she have are these, for example:

$$\sin\alpha=\frac{1}{\csc\alpha}$$

and:

$$\tan\alpha=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}$$

I'm trying to browse for help, but I don't know wath to search for. Where to begin.

---

I was able to talk with a classmate of hers, she explain me this:

In each problem, we need to use all the needed functions ([Right angled triangle definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Right-angled_triangle_definitions)).

In the first problem:

$$\sin\alpha=\frac{8\sqrt{11}}{9}$$

We need to solve the $\cos$ then $\sec$ then $\csc$ then $\tan$ then $\cot$. Does this makes any sense?

Comment: Here is a hint for one of them. $-1 \le \sin(x) \le 1$. Is $\frac{ 8 \sqrt{11}}{9}$ in that interval ?

Comment: For the first equation, $\frac{8\sqrt{11}}{9}$ is greater than $1$, so there is no real answer.

Comment: By the way $\sin(x)=\frac{1}{\csc(x)} \neq \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$

Comment: I'm interested in a guide, where I can find a way to solve this. What it is =)

Comment: These seem kinda like calculator questions to me (well the second one does). http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/TrigEquations_CalcI.aspx I really like paul's notes.

Comment: And I mean you can really use a calculator for both, but the calculator will tell you something like error or whatever it says for the $\sin^{-1}(\frac{8 \sqrt{11}}{9})$ . I forgot exactly what those handheld thingys say. (Haven't owned one in ages. :p)

Comment: Is $\tg{\alpha}$ the same as $\tan{\alpha}$? It looks like tan is tg in some European languages.

Comment: @randomgirl I've just found that those are right-angled triangle definitions

Comment: @onetoinfinity yes, is the same as $\tan\alpha$

Comment: @randomgirl I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

The first two are a slightly different kind of question than the bottom two. The first are basically asking "is (value on the right) anywhere in the range of (trig function on the left)?"

For $$\sin{\alpha} = \frac{8\sqrt{11}}{9}$$ there is no $\alpha$ that satisfies the equation since the range of $\sin$ is $[-1, 1]$, and the right-hand value is bigger than that.

For $$\tan{\alpha} = \frac{2\sqrt{5}}{12}$$ there is an answer, since $\tan$'s range is (almost) everything. The answer will equal $\tan^{-1}(\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{12})$.

The latter two you can view as being about whether the graphs of certain trig functions cross each other or not. Actually, though $$\sin{\alpha} = \frac{1}{\cos{\alpha}}$$ is amenable to a range argument as well. The range of $\cos{\alpha}$ is $[-1, 1]$; what range do we get if we take the reciprocal of every number in there? How does it compare to the range of $\sin{\alpha}$? (They do both attain $1$ and $-1$ -- you have to show that they don't intersect there, which shouldn't be too hard).

As for the last problem, remember that $\frac{\sin{\alpha}}{\cos{\alpha}} = \tan{\alpha}$. So

$$
\begin{aligned}
\tan{\alpha} &= \sqrt{\frac{(\sin{\alpha})^2}{(\cos{\alpha})^2}}\\
&= \sqrt{\left(\frac{\sin{\alpha}}{\cos{\alpha}}\right)^2}\\
&= \sqrt{(\tan{\alpha})^2}\\
&= |\tan{\alpha}|\\
\end{aligned}
$$

(remember the absolute value). So the problem is just asking for what $\alpha$ it's true that $\tan{\alpha} = |\tan{\alpha}|$.

Comment: Thanks! The two first were the actual problems, the other two were trigonometric functions for the sin and the tan of an angle. I'm going to update my question

Comment: Okay. In that case, the notes are a bit wrong (if they weren't, the solution for the last two would be $\alpha = \text{anything}$.) $\sin{\alpha}$ just does not equal $\frac{1}{\cos{\alpha}}$, I think $\frac{1}{\csc{\alpha}}$ was probably meant. The last one is right except for that absolute value (because when you square and take the square root, the result can only be positive).

Comment: You're totally right. They were typos. =( I've fixed them now